# Как в зависимости от выбранного select показывать нужный элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть селект с 3-мя option и блок с вложенными 3 блоками. Как мне показывать вложенный блок 1 если выбран первый option и т.д. ?

Мне как бы нужно брать индекс option и под таким же индексом показывать.

Я взял код от табов JQ и попытался его переделать под селект. Но толи this не срабатывает, толи индекс не определяется. 
Подскажите куда обратить внимание?

```js
 $('select').on('change', function () {
        $(this)
            .closest('.wrapper').find('.block').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
.hero-apartment__img {
  displa: none;
}

.hero-apartment__img.active {
  display: block;
}

.block {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block.active {
  display: block;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:red;
}

.inner.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block active">
    <div class="inner active"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="inner"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="inner"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: какой блок `.block` и какой блок `.inner` в блоке нужно показать если выбрано 2 ?

Comment: @Alex блок активный. inner второй. Мне как бы неважно. Можно навешивать активный класс на все вторые .inner в каждом .block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('.wrapper .block.active .inner')
    .removeClass('active')
    .eq($(this).prop('selectedIndex'))
    .addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.hero-apartment__img {
  displa: none;
}

.hero-apartment__img.active {
  display: block;
}

.block {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block.active {
  display: block;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block active">
    <div class="inner active"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="inner"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="inner"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPD** - *чтобы класс* `active` *навешивался на* `.inner` *в каждом* `.block`:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('.wrapper .block .inner').removeClass('active')
  let i = $(this).prop('selectedIndex')
  $('.wrapper .block').each(function(k, v) {
    $(v).find('.inner').eq(i).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.hero-apartment__img {
  display: none;
}

.hero-apartment__img.active {
  display: block;
}

.block {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block.active {
  display: block;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block active">
    <div class="inner active"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="inner"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="inner"> <span>1</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="inner"> <span>3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А получается на соседние блоки он уже не ставит класс. Ставит только на первый .block.

Comment: @Григорий, так Вы же в комментарии написали - [*блок активный*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962116/#comment1610297_962116), а активный блок - блок с классом `.active`. Если Вы подразумевали иное и в этом есть необходимость, напишите пожалуйста подробнее, обновлю ответ

Comment: Да, моя ошибка. Нужно что бы класс навешивался на все .inner которые в каждом блоке .block.

Comment: @Григорий обновили ответ, смотрите код в **UPD**

Comment: Спасибо большое!